# Store mouse coordinates to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have to make a *Where's Waldo* type of game and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to store the coordinates (x, y) in the database (firestore).
For example, in the code below I have two boxes (see snippet). When I click on one of them, it displays the coordinates of where I clicked. I want to save these coordinates, so it would match when a user click on them when playing the game. I have an idea on how I would retrieve this data so it would match with the user's click, I'm struggling with saving this information to the database.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box')
const ie = document.querySelector('.para')

const getCoord = (e) => {
  let x = e.clientX;
  let y = e.clientY;
         
  let coord = `X: ${x}, Y: ${y}`
  ie.textContent = coord;
}

box.addEventListener('click', getCoord);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.char {
  display: flex;
  margin: .8rem;
}

.red,
.blue {
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="char">
    <div class="red">A</div>
    <div class="blue">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="para"></p>
```

Running the snippet you see that you get the X and Y values of where you clicked in the box. How can I store these values on firebase? I appreciate any response.

Comment: We don't know which Firebase product you're asking about. Also, are you asking how to [Add data to Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)?

Comment: @Jay I'm confused about how I'd structure that info. It'd be on firestore, yes. Thanks for your comment

Comment: It would be a document with two fields, x and y. What else is needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different approach actually. There is no point in saving all of the user click data.
You can have a JSON structure like this in your database where you store the correct coordinates for the particular pageIdentifier.

```
{
"page1":{x:98.19586181640625, y:47.1947021484375},
"page2":{x:94.19586181640625, y:44.1947021484375},
....
}
```

Once your particular page is loaded, you can do a get call to fetch the particular
page data i.e the coordinates. You can use these coordinates to cross-check with the user-clicked coordinates and proceed with the game.